# Equivalent Representations are Unitarily equivalent (up to scalar)

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, let $(\rho,V)$ and $(\tau,W)$ be 2 irreducible, equivalent representations of $G$ with intertwining isomorphism $L: V \to W$. Let $(\ ,\ )_V$ and $(\ ,\ )_W$ be $G$-invariant Hermitian inner products on $V$ and $W$ respectively.

I want to show that $\rho$ and $\tau$ are unitarily equivalent up to a positive, real scalar. So far I have managed to show that any 2 hermitian inner products on $V$ which are $G$-invariant w.r.t. $\rho$ must be positive, real scalar multiples of each other (using the isomorphism between $\text{Hom}(V,V)$ and the space of sesquilinear forms on $V$). From here it seems like it should be easy to conclude that $\rho$ and $\tau$ are unitarily equivalent up to scalar, but none of my attempts were successful. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equip $V$ and $W$ with some inner products which make $\rho$ and $\tau$ act by unitary operators. All that remains to be seen is that we can replace the isomorphism $L \colon V \to W$ with a unitary isomorphism. Consider the adjoint $L^* \colon W \to V$.

Since $L^*$ is an isomorphism of representations, so is $L^* L \colon V \to V$. Since $V$ is irreducible, the operator $L^* L$ must be a scalar multiple of the identity: $L^* L = \lambda \operatorname{id}_V$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. We can see by
$$\lambda (v, v) = (L^* L v, v) = (L v, L v) > 0$$
that $\lambda$ is a positive real number, and hence defining
$$ U = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} L$$
we get an operator satisfying $U^*U = \operatorname{id}_V$, which is a unitary isomorphism of representations $U \colon V \to W$.

Comment: Why would the adjoint be an intertwining operator? Wouldn't there be an extra complex conjugate? I know that the adjoint (w.r.t. dual ONB) is an intertwining operator for the dual representations $L^\ast : W^\ast \to V^\ast$, and the dual representations are not equivalent to the original representations, rather it's equivalent to their complex conjugate.

Comment: @AustinShiner Since $L$ satisfies $L \rho(g) = \tau(g) L$ for all elements $g \in G$, taking adjoints of all operators gives $\rho(g)^* L^* = L^* \tau(g)^*$. However, because we are working with inner products where $\rho(g)$ and $\tau(g)$ are unitary, we have $\rho(g)^* = \rho(g)^{-1} = \rho(g^{-1})$, and so we get $\rho(g) L^* = L^* \tau(g)$ for all $g \in G$. The operation of taking adjoints is conjugate-linear, but the adjoint operator itself is still complex-linear, so $L^* \colon W \to V$ is still a complex-linear map.

Comment: But isn't the inner product adjoint (the map $L^\ast: W \to V$) different from the operator adjoint (the map $L^\ast: W^\ast \to V^\ast$)? In particular, the matrix of the first one (w.r.t an ONB) is the conjugate tranpose, while the matrix of the second one is just the transpose, so they are off by a complex conjugate. Perhaps I misunderstood which adjoint you are referring to.

Comment: @AustinShiner: The map $(L \mapsto L^*)$ is only a conjugate-linear map, but the operator $L^*$ itself is complex-linear. If you want to think in terms of matrices with respect to an orthonormal basis, $(L \mapsto L^*)$ is taking the conjugate-transpose of each entry, but the matrix $L^*$ you end up with is still just a matrix that multiplies with vectors in the usual way.

Comment: @AustinShiner The reason we don't need to consider $L^* \colon W^* \to V^*$ is because both $W$ and $V$ are already inner product spaces, and so have a canonical conjugate-linear identification with their dual spaces, for example $W \to W^*$ by $w \mapsto (w, -)$, where the inner product is conjugate-linear in its first argument and linear in its second. If everything is a Hilbert space then adjoints do not require dual spaces to be canonically defined.